# ayuda con query para actualizar con campos separados por comas

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo la tabla

```
COSAS

CAMPOA   CAMPOB
Frutas   Manzana
Frutas   Peras
Frutas   Uvas
Lacteos  Yogur

CANTIDAD
CAMPOC   CAMPOD
Frutas   1
Manzana  2
Peras    3
Yogur    1
Lacteos  1
```

necesito una consulta que me ponsiga esto:

CAMPO A y CAMPO C
De tal modo que quedaria

```
Frutas   1,2,3
Lacteos  1,1
```

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta el código que has intentando y que error específico tienes con eso. Mira esta guía: __[mcve]__.

Comment: Hola. He intentado aclararlo un poco. Lo he puesto en el mensaje principal

Comment: El select xxxx y jjjj lo he sustituido con el codigo donde aparece el listagg

Comment: Si, quiero mandar al campo C, campo separado por comas despues de hacer una consulta con los campos A y B seperados por comas sobre otra tabla

Comment: He corregido el ejemplo, ahora creo que esta mas claro. Saludos!

Comment: Hola, la pregunta está mas clara (aunque un tanto rara). Lo único es que ya no incluyes la consulta que tu has construido como intento. Te sugiero de volver a incluir tu intento para que se vea que has hecho un esfuerzo por resolver el problema. Cuando las preguntas no dejan claro que hubo esfuerzo, tienden a no ser muy bien recibidas.

Comment: Me parece que para que sea reabierta la pregunta, ademas de lo que pide sstan, deberias explicar como se relacionan campoA y campoC, porque hasta ahora se conectan magicamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviamente, para lograr tu resultado, es necesario hacer un join entre las 2 tablas. Lo raro de tu pregunta es que `CANTIDAD.CAMPOC` contiene valores de ambas columnas de la tabla `COSAS`. O sea que `COSAS.CAMPOA` cumple una doble función de categorizar el `CAMPOB` pero también de hacer join con la tabla `CANTIDAD`. Nuevamente, ese diseño me parece bien extraño.

En todo caso, lo que pides sí es posible, pero primero hay que corregir el diseño de forma virtual, haciendo que todos los valores de la tabla `COSAS` a los que necesitas hacer un join queden en la misma columna. Este se logra con la consulta siguiente:

```
select distinct a as categoria,
                a as elemento
  from cosas
 union all
select a as categoria,
       b as elemento
  from cosas
```

Ya después es fácil agregarle el join y el `LISTAGG`:

```
with cte as (
  select distinct a as categoria,
                  a as elemento
    from cosas
   union all
  select a as categoria,
         b as elemento
    from cosas
)
select t.categoria,
       listagg(c.d, ',') within group (order by c.d) as lista_cantidades
  from cte t
  join cantidad c
    on c.c = t.elemento
 group by t.categoria
```

---

**Setup**

```
create table cosas (
  a varchar2(50) not null,
  b varchar2(50) not null
)
/

create table cantidad (
  c varchar2(50) not null,
  d number(5) not null
)
/

insert all
  into cosas (a,b) values ('Frutas', 'Manzana')
  into cosas (a,b) values ('Frutas', 'Peras')
  into cosas (a,b) values ('Frutas', 'Uvas')
  into cosas (a,b) values ('Lacteos', 'Yogur')
select null from dual
/

insert all
  into cantidad (c,d) values ('Frutas', 1)
  into cantidad (c,d) values ('Manzana', 2)
  into cantidad (c,d) values ('Peras', 3)
  into cantidad (c,d) values ('Yogur', 1)
  into cantidad (c,d) values ('Lacteos', 1)
select null from dual
/
```

Comment: Respeto los votos negativos. Tampoco me molesta si me dejan saber si he cometido algún error en la respuesta.